# Confusion in the Bitwise operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I just started to learn c language. I have a question about the result of bitwise operations. In the following code, why we get a different result from c and d? How do we have 72 as the value of d?

```
char a = 41;//101001
char b = (a<<5);//32 or 100000
char c = (b>>2);//8 or 1000
char d = (a<<5)>>2;//72 or 1001000
printf("a= %d , b=%d, b=%d , d=%d\n", a, b,c,d);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When any type or arithmetic operation is performed on a type smaller than `int`, the value is promoted to `int` within the expression.  Then when the result is saved to a `char`, all but the lowest order byte are truncated.

This covered in section 6.3.1.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **2** The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> —  An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than
>   `int` or `unsigned int`) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less  than 
>   or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int` and `unsigned int`.
>
> —  A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as 
>   restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is 
>   converted  to  an `int`; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an 
>   `unsigned int`. These  are  called  the *integer promotions*.  All  other
>   types are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions.

In the case of `c`, you first do `a<<5`.  Before this happens, the value of `a` in this expression is promoted in `int`, so the result can be larger than a `char`.

This results in the binary value `10100100000` (decimal 1312).  This is then saved to `b` which has type `char`, so only the lower 8 bits (`00100000`, decimal 8) are retained.  So `b` now has the value of 8.

Then we perform `b>>2` giving us binary `00001000` (decimal 8) which is saved in `c`.

In the case of `d`, we perform `a<<5` as before (with the value of `a` being promoted to `int`) getting binary `10100100000`.  Now this value is shifted right by 2 resulting in `00101001000` (decimal 328).  This is then saved to `d` which is of type `char`, so only the lower 8 bits are saved (`01001000`, decimal 72).  So `d` now as the value of 72.

Comment: OP also asked "How do we have 72 as the value of d?"  (to which the answer might be `(char)(a<<5) >> 2`)